# How to save trace info into a file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, trace

I am tracing my ASPX page by enabling tracing in `web.config` (`<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true"/>`)

How could i save this information (specifically the request headers) into a log file.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: How have you configured your trace listeners?

Comment: @Oded - i am sorry, but i am not getting your point. I have just a normal web application with the web.config file. I have enabled the trace using <trace enabled="true" />. Is there anything i am missing out?

Comment: Yes. Just enabling trace is not enough. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: @Oded: Oh, thanks buddy. Thats a very good information.

Comment: @Oded Please add this as an answer. This can we useful for other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply enabling tracing the way your have is not enough - you need to configure what to trace and what to do with the trace.

See [Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx) and [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Check the below link which show various options of tracing

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82290/Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Trace-the-ASP-NET-Applicatio

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers)
 {
     YourLoggingMethod(key, HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[key]);
 }
```