# How can I view .NET trace logs in TeamCity?

Tags: .net, nunit, teamcity

I have a few C# integration tests that are run every night by Team City and the NUnit test runner. It would be very helpful if when a test fails the Trace logs could be made visible within the Team City build log.

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean to say that your tests make http requests and that you would like the trace files on disk? If so, have a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141723/how-to-save-trace-info-into-a-file.

Comment: I mean that the Nunit tests call methods with Trace.TraceError() statements. I was wondering how I could see those within Team City?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All console output is shown in the build log. Not quite sure if Trace-logs are displayed there (it might even be configurable somewhere?)

Click on a build, go to the tests tab. To the right of all tests there is a small arrow, click it and hit "Show in build log", and you'll be taken directly to the output of that test. Usually there's not a lot of interesting stuff for a successful test. Failed tests have their own view with all the output you normally get in your test runner.

Comment: Thanks Arve, that worked. I just created a trace listener to output to the console and I can see all the info in the build log.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
Console.WriteLine("")
```

It will appear in your TeamCity build log, might be not the best solution in the long run but for temporary test debugging this should suffice.